# Sending a file from java to angular is malforming/encoding data

Tags: java, encoding, restangular

I have two types of files I need to send from my server to the client.  I am using angularjs as a client side and java on the server.  I am having no issues sending plain text files and downloading the contents of them in a file.  Where I am hitting a snag is a pcap.  In some cases I want to request the pcap and download.  But something is encoding the data and I am not quite sure what.  I have spent hours trying the following and a few different combos of things.

My Java looks like:

```
  @GET
  @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM})
  @Path("/{id}/packet/download")
  public static Response downloadFile(String filePath) {
    ResponseBuilder rb;
    File file = new File(filePath);

    if (file.exists()) {
      rb = Response.ok(file, mimeType);
      rb.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getName());
      rb.header("Content-Length", file.length());
    } else { //
      rb = Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    return rb.build();
  }
```

And my javascript:

```
that.savePacket = function(item) {
  var url = 'rs/' + that.baseUrl + '/' + item.r$itemData.id + '/packet/download';
  return restangularInstance.one(url).get().then(function(response) {
    var file = {};
    file.name = parseFileName(response.headers('Content-Disposition'));
    file.data = response.data;
    file.isText = file.name.endsWith('.txt');
    var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.download = file.name;
    a.click();
    return file;
  });
};
```

On the receiving end my download save dialog pops up properly and the file downloads.  However for some reason or another you can tell the data was tampered along the way when it is a `pcap`.

When I take a hexdump of the file before it is sent we see the following:

```
0000000 c3d4 a1b2 0002 0004 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000060 9090 9090 9090 9090 9090 9090 9090 9090
```

But after the file is downloaded I see:

```
0000000 bfef c3bd efb2 bdbf 0002 0004 0000 0000
0001190 bfef efbd bdbf bfef efbd bdbf bfef efbd
00011a0 bdbf bfef 00bd
```

As far as the alternative to the above I have tried:

- `Files.readAllBytes(path);` and pushing the byte array into the response
- `String mimeType = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(file);` and pushing the type into type into the response creation.
- Forcing the mime to be `application/cap`

Under each test I found that for some reason or another my text files worked fine but the pcap was always malformed.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that restangular was tampering with the data.  Adding a `.withHttpConfig({responseType: 'arraybuffer'})` into the call stack worked.